# getResourceAsStream returning null on image path

Tags: java, jar

I have read many other questions and resources regarding this issue and am still getting nowhere. I asked a question about this the other day and was referred to the other questions again. Maybe I am just not getting it but I have been trying to getResourceAsStream for my java project for 2 days so I can get the jar to work to no avail.

I have two places in my project causing issues. My buffered image class:

```
public static BufferedImage loadImage(String fileName) {
        try { 
            File file = new File(fileName);           
            //System.out.println("Is the file there for " + fileName + " : "  + file.exists());
            BufferedImage sub = ImageIO.read(file); 
            return toCompatibleImage(sub);
        }
        catch (IOException e) { 
            System.out.println("Image load failed: " +fileName);
//          e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My GifHandler class:

```
public enum GifHandler {
    Mouse("Resources/Images/cursor/", ".gif", 45, 45),
    Coaster("Resources/Images/animatedCoaster/", ".gif", Carnies.PWIDTH, Carnies.PHEIGHT/2),
    Fire("Resources/Images/fire/", ".gif", 100, 100);

    public BufferedImage[] sequence;
    int playing = 0;

    GifHandler(String dir_name, String type, int width, int height) {
        int numImgs = new File(dir_name).list().length;
        if (sequence == null) {
            sequence = new BufferedImage[numImgs];
            for (int i = 0; i < numImgs; i++) {
                sequence[i] = ImageLoader.loadScaledImage(dir_name + i + type, width, height, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have added the resources folder to my build path libraries. My project file structure is like this: 
"Project/src/defaultpackage/classfiles"
"Project/resources/Images/imagefiles"
I want to reference the imagefiles from the classfiles, obviously.
I have tried changing to getResourceAsStream, but always get null on the path.

For example, a change to the imageLoader class as shown, returns null:

String path = ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName).toString();
Where fileName is passed in as "resource/Images/alphabet.png" for example. 
I've tried every combination of adding and removing /, only referencing the /alphabet.png without leading folders etc. I am at the end of my rope. Please help out. If I haven't linked enough code for this to make sense, the repo for it is at github.com/madamsmall/carnies

Comment: Really? None of the dozen duplicates or so that popped up when you typed your question subject were of any help?

Comment: That's correct. I have legitimately looked at several and not resolved it.

Comment: It works exactly one way, as all those questions and answers demonstrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My project file structure is like this: "Project/src/defaultpackage/classfiles" "Project/resources/Images/imagefiles"

When you use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`, the program will start it's search from the location of the calling class. So by passing `"resource/Images/alphabet.png"`, you're saying that `resources` is in `classfiles`, which it isn't. To fix it, you need to allow the search to be traversed back. You can do that by adding a `/` to the path. So `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource/Images/alphabet.png")`

Another option is to use the the class loader, which will search from the the root. In that case, you don't need the extra `/` and your current path would be correct. `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resource/Images/alphabet.png");`

**Note:** `getClass()` and `ImageLoader.class` are interchangeable in most cases, in case you're wondering why I used `getClass()`

---

**UPDATE**

Use this example as a test

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/resource/images/alphabet.png");
        Image image = ImageIO.read(is);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);

    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I just noticed that `resource` is not in your `src` which it should be, so when it's built, it gets built into the class path.

---

**UPDATE 3**

If you want to get a list of all the file names, you can use this method. Then you can do whatever you want with those file names.

```
private String[] getFileNames() throws URISyntaxException {
    URL url = getClass().getResource("/resources/images/");
    File file = new File(url.toURI());
    String[] fileNames = file.list();
    for (String s : fileNames) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    return fileNames;
}
```

Comment: I tried using String path = ImageLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resource/Images/alphabet.png").toString();     This is still null.

Comment: How are you use `path`?

Comment: I am using path to plug in to File file = new File(path);   However, it never gets that far as the getResource line returns null.

Comment: No, you don't wan't to use a `File` when loading an embedded resource. See my example, and test it out.

Comment: I did this:   public static BufferedImage loadImage(String fileName) {
    InputStream is = ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/resource/images/alphabet.png");
         Image image;
   try {
    image = ImageIO.read(is);
      JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
   } catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
   }}      Still have a null pointer on the line ImageIO.read(is);

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, that `resource` should be in the `src`. OOPs!

Comment: I moved the resources folder to src, still null. My file structure is now "Project/src/resources/Images..." and "Project/src/default package/classfiles"

Comment: works fine for me. note your package is called `resources` and you are using `resource` in your path

Comment: True, I did mistype that here. I had already corrected it in my program though, it was only a product of hasty typing in my question.

Comment: Don't know what you're doing wrong. I tested it with your exact file structure and it works fine

Comment: I went through it again and it worked for imageLoader! My build path had issues after I moved the resources file so the changes weren't taking effect when I hit play. Thank you so much. I am trying to apply the changes to the GifHandler class now and still having trouble since it's a bit different but going to try to make it work with your method.

Comment: Now my issue seems to be with the line  int numImgs = new File(path).list().length;

Comment: IT WORKED> I had to hard code the number of images instead of doing a .length() call but it WORKSSSS. You are wonderful.

Comment: See my **UPDATE 3** for a helper method. I just tested it, and it gives me all the file names in the package. You can then use each file name to concatenate your resource string. That way you don't have to hard code the number of images. What if it changes ;)

Comment: @peeskillet I am not sure what is my root, what should I give as path to print all filenames at root?